# Set border size

Tags: javafx-2, javafx, javafx-8

I want to make the border of a borderpane more round and bold.

I tested this code:

```
bpi.setStyle("-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f2f2f2, #d4d4d4);"
                + " -fx-border: 12px solid; -fx-border-color: white; -fx-background-radius: 15.0;"
                + " -fx-border-radius: 15.0");
```

I get this result:

[image]

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Why your current approach doesn't work**

Don't use `-fx-border` (it doesn't even currently exist in JavaFX CSS).

Though there are other `fx-border-*` attributes such as `-fx-border-color`, `-fx-border-width` and `-fx-border-radius`, I wouldn't recommend them either.

**Suggested Approach**

Instead, use a combination of layered attributes:

- `-fx-background-color`
- `-fx-background-insets`
- `-fx-background-radius`

You can find documentation on these CSS attribute features in the [JavaFX CSS reference guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Although using `-fx-background-*` attributes for a border seems strange:

1. It is the way that all of the borders in the [default JavaFX modena.css stylesheet](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/controls/rt/file/tip/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) are handled.
2. In my experience, when borders are rounded, applying borders in this way is simpler and gives better results than using `-fx-border-*` attributes.

**Sample Code**

For instance, here is an example fxml file which applies the standard [modena.css](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) style attribute values for "button like things" to a BorderPane.  (modena.css comes from [Java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html)).

[image: buttonlike]

You can copy and paste the fxml and css, then load them up in [SceneBuilder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/tools/index.html) to see what it looks like.

*button-like.css*

```
.button-like {
  -fx-background-color: 
       -fx-shadow-highlight-color, 
       -fx-outer-border, 
       -fx-inner-border, 
       -fx-body-color;
  -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
  -fx-background-radius: 3px, 3px, 2px, 1px;
}
```

*button-like.fxml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?scenebuilder-stylesheet button-like.css?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
            minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="131.0"
            prefWidth="196.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
  <children>
    <BorderPane layoutX="48.0" layoutY="26.0" prefHeight="79.0" prefWidth="100.0"
                styleClass="button-like" 
    />
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Note**

You wouldn't actually want to apply the above exact style in your application for styling something like a [BorderPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html), as that is not a "button like thing".  Using the same styling for something that is not a button would confuse the user.  But the sample approach should demonstrate the general idea on layering backgrounds to achieve the style you want.

**Additional Example**

This example uses the same FXML layout file defined above, just a different stylesheet to achieve a different style.

[image: imageicon]

```
AnchorPane {
  -fx-background-color: #232732;
}

.button-like {
  -fx-outer-border: white;
  -fx-body-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FAFAFA, #EAEAEA);
  -fx-background-color: 
       -fx-outer-border, 
       -fx-body-color;
  -fx-background-insets: 0, 6;
  -fx-background-radius: 6px, 0px;
  -fx-background-image: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/appicns/simplified-app/64/appicns-Chrome-icon.png');
  -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -fx-background-position: center;
}

/**
Icon license: Free for non-commercial use.
Icon license Commercial usage: Not allowed
Icon source: http://appicns.com
*/
```

Comment: One more question. How I can I can make the border of the component to look like these panels https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2568400 I would like to increase the size of the border and make it white.

Comment: @Peter I added an additional example to the answer to demonstrate how to generate styles similar to those you linked in your comment.  The general approach is not different than the first button-like example - just layer backgrounds.

Comment: From CSS reference , The Link you mentioned there is -fx-border-color property. look http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region.

Comment: @Mubasher agreed that there is a `-fx-border-color` property, I just don't recommend using it for most applications as usually the `-fx-background*` attributes are better alternatives, especially for the Peter's original question which wants bold round borders.

Comment: I want Just Bottom border , How can i achieve this in javafx

Comment: @Mubasher, please ask new questions as new questions, thanks.

Comment: I have managed to achieve the bottom border by using this style. "-fx-border-style: hidden hidden solid hidden;"