# How do you create a rounded border with a semi transparent background for a button in JavaFX?

Tags: css, javafx-8

I want to create buttons like this in JavaFX (not html).

http://jsfiddle.net/x7dRU/3/

(hover on them to see the effect)

[Stupid Stackoverflow insists on me posting jsfiddle code here which isn't relevant]
`<li><a href="/help/2/">Button 1</a></li`>

So with a rounded border and a transparent background. Unfortunately the background/insets technique seems to overwrite the content from outside to in. So if you draw a bright border, then you can't undo the brightness to create a dark&transparent background without hardcoding the colour. I.e. it's not write once, run everywhere, on different coloured panels.

-fx-border-color doesn't seem to support rounding or at least isn't recommended here [Set border size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154110/set-border-size) . I imagine the rounding of the border doesn't sync with the rounding of the background.

Seems HTML5 has the edge on this one then. Tell me I'm wrong :-) ...although I suspect my question can't be done without specifying the colour for each and every button context.

**Browny points.**
Note, I realise I've coloured the white border greenish (context sensitive), I'm happy with a border of semi-transparent white as a solution. First prize would be a burn/dodge/etc(background-colour) function ala photoshop.

**Plan B.**
It doesn't look so bad without rounded edges, so maybe I should just resort to -fx-border-color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background info**

Have a look at the information in the css documentation on ["looked-up colors"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor)(scroll down a little, beyond the named color section).

The way these basically work, is that you can define a "looked up color" (i.e. a color-valued variable) and apply it to a node in the scene graph. The value is inherited by any node descended from that node in the scene graph.

Now have a browse through the default style sheet, [modena.css](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8/master/rt/file/f89b7dc932af/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css). The way this works is that almost everything is defined in terms of a very short list of looked-up colors. The consequence is that you can readily "theme" your applications just by redefining those colors on the root of the scene. Try adding this stylesheet to your favorite JavaFX application:

```
.root {
    -fx-base: #c7dec7;
    -fx-accent: #00c996 ;
    -fx-default-button: #abedd8 ;
    -fx-focus-color: #03d39e;
    -fx-faint-focus-color: #03d39e22;
}
```

As you've observed, `-fx-border` is not used at all in the default stylesheet; instead borders are implemented by defining "nested" background colors which are essentially rectangular fills laid on top of each other. This is apparently more efficient (quite considerably so, by my understanding). So you are correct that making the inner of two backgrounds transparent will simply reveal the "outer" border color, not the color of the background.

**How to achieve what you're looking for**

The background of a pane defaults to the looked-up color `-fx-background`, which in turn defaults to a lighter version of `-fx-base`. So if you stick to changing the color of the pane containing the buttons by changing `-fx-background` or `-fx-base`, then you can make the button appear transparent by setting its background to

```
-fx-background-color: (some-border-color), -fx-background ;
```

The default borders for buttons contain three values; `-fx-shadow-highlight`, `-fx-outer-border`, and `-fx-inner-border`. You could override the values for these individually, or just redefine the background color as you need.

An approximation to what you want is in this example: you can mess with the exact values for the thickness of the border (from the second `-fx-background-insets` value) and the radius of the corners to get it as you need. If you want to get fancy with it, play with combinations of ladders and gradients.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class StyledButtonExample extends Application {

    private int currentColorIndex = 0 ;
    private final String[] baseColors = new String[] {"#8ec919", "#bfe7ff", "#e6e6fa",
            "#ffcfaf", "#fff7f7", "#3f474f"};

    private StackPane root ;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        root = new StackPane();
        Button button = new Button("Change colors");
        button.setOnAction(event -> changeColors());
        root.getChildren().add(button);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("transparent-button.css").toExternalForm());
        root.setStyle("-fx-base: "+baseColors[0]+";");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void changeColors() {
        currentColorIndex = (currentColorIndex + 1) % baseColors.length ;
        root.setStyle("-fx-base: "+baseColors[currentColorIndex]+";");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

transparent-button.css:

```
.button {
    -fx-background-color: derive(-fx-base, 60%), -fx-background ; 
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1px ;
    -fx-background-radius: 4px, 0 ;
}
 .button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #fff, derive(-fx-background, -5%) ;
}
```

Comment: Thanx! Haven't tried it out yet, but I can see that it will work. I did know about "looked up" colours, but I didn't think to use the same looked up colour in both the button and the panel... and the fact that changing it in the button will have no effect on the parent panels, preserving any other modifications. That didn't come obvious because I would have thought that transparent Hboxs for layout purposes only etc may reset -fx-background-color?? and have cascading effects?

Comment: `-fx-background-color` is a property, not a looked-up color; `-fx-background` is a looked-up color. So setting `-fx-background-color` does not propagate to children.

Comment: I imagine since you're relying on -fx-background, this technique won't scale if the button exists over an image/gradient/pattern etc. I.e. you're relying on hacking matching colours to create the effect, rather than simulating a pane of glass. Another reason it escaped my intuition.

Comment: Over an image definitely wouldn't work. If the gradient were the background color of the enclosing pane, that should work. Pattern... I would have to try it. But yes, if you want true transparency, I think you cannot use the overlaid-background technique for the borders.